# Release upgrade to 22.10 fails due to missing release file in Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

In Ubuntu 22.04 I am running

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and get

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for 
repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 
'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu jammy 
Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I basically can't update Ubuntu anymore. Is the release file causing the problem? My network is fine, definitely connected to the internet.

Comment: Remove the mentioned ppa and all software installed from it from your system.

Comment: Is their a guide on how to do this?

Comment: `sudo apt install ppa-purge` and `sudo ppa-purge ppa:alexeftimie/ppa` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! I get: ~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:alexeftimie/ppa
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: In fact, good news, used this (first answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) and its now updating: sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:alexeftimie/ppa